# Can I pass a dynamic value from craft CMS to another template as well as a string value?

Tags: symfony, twig, octobercms, craftcms

Can I pass a dynamic value from craft CMS using twig to another template as well as a string value?
Using the following gives me a syntax error

"Twig_Error_Syntax: A hash key must be followed by a colon (:).
Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "," ("punctuation" expected with value ":") "

```
        {% set myEntry= craft.entries.slug('myEntry').first %}
        {% embed '_layouts/_hero' with {
            'extraClasses': "{{ myEntry.featuredBgPosition }} hero--medium",
            'heroImage': myEntry.featuredImage.first
        } %}
```

Other answers say to not use curly braces but this doesn't work either

`'extraClasses': myEntry.featuredBgPosition "hero--medium",`

and when using it within the quotations I get the string myEntry.featuredBgPosition as a class

`'extraClasses': myEntry.featuredBgPosition "hero--medium",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers that suggest removing the curly braces are correct, but you need to concatentate strings with variables.

```
        {% set myEntry= craft.entries.slug('myEntry').first %}
        {% embed '_layouts/_hero' with {
            'extraClasses': myEntry.featuredBgPosition ~ " hero--medium",
            'heroImage': myEntry.featuredImage.first
        } %}
```

Comment: stackoverflow.com/q/56338792/8631622 Please look into this problem. I did everything I could. But I could not solve this problem @emarref